# Google Maps - How do I efficiently create a polygon with many points?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, layer, geopoints

I need a polygon for every German state. I go all the `GeoPoints` in one `JavaScript`-file but the file is because of the amout of points about `4MB`. I've been googling and thinking about this problem all day but couldn't figure out a solution...

How can I use `Google Maps` polygons without forcing the user to download a huge js-file with the coordinates?

Thanks!
Ron

Comment: Arrghhh, sorry, I had just been answering another question regarding a circle, so I had posted an answer about creating a circle. Deleted now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode the polygon points to vastly reduce the size of the javascript file. To do this, you must include the geometry library.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Encoding

Comment: this thing is great! my JS file shrinked from more than 3MB to about 200k

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a FusionTablesLayer to display the polygons.  They are available in the Natural Earth data set that is publicly available.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Germany)

You could do the same with your points and a KmlLayer if you convert your data to KML.

Answer (score 0):

Well... somehow the points have to get to the user. You could think of the following solutions to reduce the data usage:

- Use different polygons for different zoom levels. For example zoomed out you won't need the full details.
- only send parts of your polygon back to the user. You can for example send the viewport coordinates to an AJAX script. This one queries your database and/or shapefile and only returns the polygon parts that are visible in the user's viewport
- preprocess tiles. If you can generate images from your shape, you can overlay these on Google Maps.